# Force requests to use the same connection

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap, connection

I'm consuming a SOAP service with my program. My service provider has complained that my program establishes a new connection with every request and their threshold for established connections is 150. So the connection on their side has an "established" state and this causes problems apparently.

On my side, I just add the service's reference points and start consuming their functions. I don't intervene with any connection issues. I just use my user/pass as authentication. But is there a way to force my program to always use the same connection for retrieving data from this SOAP service?

Comment: You'll need to implement pooling. Here is a pretty good article. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2007/11/14/a-sample-for-wcf-client-proxy-pooling.aspx

Comment: By default the HttpWebRequest (which is used by the SOAP client) will reuse TCP connections. Could there be a load balancer between your client code and the SOAP service which is terminating the connections between the frontend and the backend? For example it might be appending a `Connection: close` request header to all requests sent from the client to the backend.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov and what do you mean by a load balancer, can you give me an example?

Comment: There are many popular load balancers out there such as `HAProxy` or even hardware F5 load balancers. So basically when your client is requesting for example `http://example.com/someservice` this request is first hitting the load balancer which is then distributing the request to the actual web nodes on which the SOAP service is hosted.

Comment: Do you close the client properly when you're done with it? I wonder why your connections are staying open (according to the server).

Comment: I edited my program to dispose the service object every time the function has done its work. Typically, I think it's the server that has to take care of the connections @TimS. Isn't it. Since I never had this problem with the other services we are using. But I did it and if it worked then you have the correct answer.